# Wanted to sort data order by Desig id, but in vain

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select
    desig_id,ename,
    desig_desc,
    mobile,email,
    hl_id,
    substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(job_desc, ';'),1) 
from
(
 select
     desig_id,ename,
     desig_desc,
     mobile,
     email,
     hl_id,
     job_desc,
     count(*)  OVER ( partition by hl_id ) cnt,
     ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( partition by hl_id order by desig_id asc) seq
 from assignjob 
 where
     hl_id is not null and
     br_name ='Information Technology Div.' 
 )
 where 
     seq=cntstart with seq=1 connect by prior seq+1=seq and prior hl_id=hl_id ;
```

In the above sql, i have tried to sort my data in ascending order of designation id. But do not know where to place order by keyword to do this work.
Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try as put it in the end

```
select
    desig_id,ename,
    desig_desc,
    mobile,email,
    hl_id,
    substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(job_desc, ';'),1) 
from
(
 select
     desig_id,ename,
     desig_desc,
     mobile,
     email,
     hl_id,
     job_desc,
     count(*)  OVER ( partition by hl_id ) cnt,
     ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( partition by hl_id order by desig_id asc) seq
 from assignjob 
 where
     hl_id is not null and
     br_name ='Information Technology Div.' 
 )
 where 
     seq=cntstart with seq=1 connect by prior seq+1=seq and prior hl_id=hl_id
 order by desig_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the order by at the end of connect by:

```
select
    desig_id,ename,
    desig_desc,
    other fields
from
(
   --------All inner query here --------------
 )
 where 
     seq=cntstart with seq=1 connect by prior seq+1=seq and prior hl_id=hl_id 
     ORDER BY DESIG_ID
;
```

Sample fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b2c1/7)